# Getting error while making mSuperdrive and mBeam API Calls in Postman Collection

Tags: edgeengine

I am working on mimik Smart-car-use-case Postman Simulation. As in **[C2]  → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1)**, I have added an image locally on Car 1, and Check the mimiked file by calling **[C3]**

and then I made **[C4] → mbeam NODE1 GET  play_queue** api call and got the list of files in mBeam play_queue as below.

[image]

After that I **deleted** the image which I have added in **[C2]** Api Call,
and again I hit Send on **[C3]** , I am getting the following error,

[image]

- Since the image is in mBeam play_queue why am I getting error, when i delete the actual image?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the image being added to play_queue, the physical file still needs to reside in origin. The reason you are getting 404 is because the the actual file is gone due to your deletion.